# Flask form to receive text box and file upload

Tags: html, forms, http, flask

I have an HTML form in my `/templates` that takes a text query and a file upload as input.

**HTML**

```
    <form action="/submitted" enctype=multipart/form-data method="POST" onsubmit="showDiv('loading')">
      <input type="text" name="query" size="50" required><br>
      <input type="file" id="fileSelect" name="file" accept=".csv">
      <input type="submit" id="query_submit">
   </form>
```

Saving the file works from flask when the `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data` but accessing `request.form` causes a 400 error which I read is due to a missing key error. And vice versa, if I remove the `enctype`, I get a 400 error but the `request.form` which contains the query is accessible.

```
@app.route("/submitted", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submitted():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form

        query = result['query']

        if not result['file']:
            datapath = 'static/iris.csv'
            plot_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        else:
            f = request.files['file']
            f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],\
                     filename))

        return render_template("submitted.html")
```

What is the proper way to read multiple input types (text, file) in the same form? Or should I make a separate form for the file?

Thanks!

Comment: can u put your code for `submmited` method as well

Answer (score 2):

In your function for the route `/submitted`, you need to receive the files using the function `request.files`, and the regular data using `request.form.get`

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was when trying to access `request.form['file']` to check if there was no file uploaded. With a form that accepts a file, for some reason that is a key error. So instead I use `request.files` to check for missing file. Here is a working `/submitted` function.

```
@app.route("/submitted", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submitted():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form

        query = result['query']

        if 'file' not in request.files:
            datapath = 'static/iris.csv'
            plot_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        else:
            f = request.files['file']
            f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],\
                     filename))

        return render_template("submitted.html")
```